# Are there different outcomes for the Dark Brotherhood questline?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm near the end of the Dark Brotherhood questline and during my last mission, things went pretty badly. Now I'm wondering if my decisions had anything to do with it. Here's the situation:

> Astrid is the one who sold me out to the Imperials and I've been taking her orders from the very beginning. I delayed talking to Amaund at her request. Following that, I killed Cicero instead of sparing his life. Thanks to her, the Imperials mass-murdered my sanctuary and burned it to the ground. That left me thinking that if I hadn't listened to her, things might be better off.

Does making different choices change the outcome of the Dark Brotherhood questline?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this always happens regardless.  There is nothing you can do to avoid that outcome.

Comment: I was just going to put a frowny face but it wasn't enough characters. So... :(

Comment: Well, you *can* make some decisions along the way differently. You don't have to kill a certain fellow member of the Brotherhood for instance...

Comment: You don't _have_ to kill him, but I wanted to slaughter that obnoxious little juggalo before I knew it was an option.

Comment: I must be one of the few people who actually like Cicero because I know he's meant to be intentionally annoying :P

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I know I don't have to kill him and that was the point to my question. I wanted to know if I didn't kill him, could I avoid everything that happens at the sanctuary.

Comment: @spugsley no, it doesn't change anything.  I left him alive in my game and the result was the same.

Comment: @yx. thanks for confirming :) I wish there were different outcomes...it would make things a lot more interesting

Answer (score 8):

There is one point during the quest line where you can change the outcome, though in a very different way.

> When you are in the Abandoned Shack, kill Astrid instead of one of the others guys. This will trigger a quest where in the end YOU will destroy the brotherhood.

Comment: Wow! I had no idea. That's pretty incredible. I think I might have to try this out on my next playthrough. Thanks for sharing!